# Help with the notation $(x,t)\in \mathbb R^n \times (0,\infty)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory, notation, vectors

> What is the meaning of $$(x,t)\in \mathbb R^n \times (0,\infty)\quad ?\tag 1\label1$$

I guess $x$ is a $n$-vector and $t$ is just a scalar, i.e. 
\begin{align}
x&=(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)\in \mathbb R^n \tag 2\\
t&\in (0,\infty) \tag 3
\end{align}

*Attempt 1:*

Does \eqref{1} mean I have , i.e.
\begin{align}
(x_1, t),  (x_2,t), \dots, (x_n,t) \tag 4
\end{align}
I.e. $n$ number of points in $\mathbb R^2$ (I guess?).

*Attempt 2:*

Or does \eqref{1} mean 
\begin{align}
(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n,t) \tag 5
\end{align}
I.e. just one point. But how many dimensions?

Comment: Attempt 2 is the correct one. The vector $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, t)$ is $(n+1)$-dimensional.

Comment: I've [edit]ed your post to add links pointing to equation (1) for easy reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is shorthand for the pair $(x, t)$ with 
$x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t \in (0, \infty)$, thus
$$
((x_1, \dotsc, x_n), t)
$$
This nested tuple can be mapped to the flat tuple
$$
(x_1, \dotsc, x_n, t)
$$
of course.